# Disable keyboard shortcuts in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, jfoenix

is it possible, to disable Ctrl+V shortcut in my JavaFx application ? its like in the textfields, user will not be able to copy text from somewhere and paste it using Ctrl+V.

here's my controller class :

```
package application;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField t1 = new JFXTextField() {
        @Override
        public void paste() {
            //do something to stop paste
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: don't fight your users ...

Comment: not fighting just wanted to know whether or not i can give such restrictions to JavaFx applications...

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by overriding the paste method and remove the line

```
super.paste();
```

it will do nothing when user try to paste

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage){

        TextField textField = new TextField(){
            @Override
            public void paste() {

            }
        };
        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(textField));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: nope its still not working, i @override the public void paste() and wrote nothing inside but its still taking paste from Ctrl+V...do i need to write something inside the paste method  ?

Comment: can u please post your code as I tried it with the code I mentioned above and it's working fine.

Comment: i have posted my controller class, please rectify it.

Comment: @AmanGupta, which version of `jfoenix` do you use?'cos the code in this answer works just fine for me.

Comment: ok I think i figured what is going on ur t1 (TextField) is already a reference to the FXML text field so what u r doing is assigning a new value to that reference and change the paste function to that new reference but the old one remain the same

Comment: @Enigo im using `jfoenix` version 9.0.0 and @AhmedEmad so what should i do in this case??...is there any other way using keyCombination or something to avoid default keyboard shortcuts ?

Comment: You can do it the other way around by creating a new textfield in the controller and add it to the pane in your scene if u want i can edit my answer with a sample code

Comment: please give a sample code it will be really helpful and i guess using fxml i cant stop keyboard shortcuts right ?

Comment: I don't think so.
but you can make your own Textfield that has an attribute to enable or disable the paste property and use it in FXML
OR u can use my answer after the edit

Comment: Accept the answer if it helps